# Configure FOSUserBundle Windows

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, fosuserbundle

Thank you for your useful answers, I receive a new error now which says the following. Any thoughts on what I need to do. Many thanks in advanced:

> RuntimeException: The autoloader expected class "IWA\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\htdocs\Rumbie\intranet/src\IWA\UserBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

My Configuration file looks like:

> 

```html
<?php

namespace UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('user');

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your namespace should have `IWA` at the start.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo.

```
$loader ->add('FOS', _DIR.'/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS');
```

should be

```
$loader ->add('FOS', __DIR__.'/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS');
```

note the double underscore either side of DIR.  But, as uelei says, you dont need it anyway

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add FOS user to autoload

comment this line

```
  #$loader ->add('FOS', _DIR.'/../vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS');
```

just add to composer requires

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I comment out that particular line I get another error which I posted at the bottom of the main question (above) RunTimeException

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, when I follow your actions I get one more error (which I have posted on the main question above - RunTimeException I was wondering how such I address this problem)

Comment: did you try       change __DIR. to __DIR__

Comment: I changed DIR to __DIR__ and I got a different error (which I have posted in the main question area above). I also followed your suggestion and commented the that particular line. I got the error that I posted above.